# What parameters of guest OS can be controlled with hypervisor?

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor

I know that some hypervisors allow you to control the amount of available RAM and disk size of guest OS. What another parameters of guest OS can be controlled with hypervisor?

(I'm asking about type 2 hypervisors only.)

Comment: Hypervisors emulate or pass through any hardware a VM owns. This would be a better question with specifics on what problem you are trying to solve, and which hypervisor you have selected.

Comment: @JohnMahowald Sorry for unclear question. I'm trying to understand the difference between emulators and hypervisors. I know that you control almost any parameter of virtual machine when you use it on top of emulator, e.g. you can control CPU clock rate. You can't control CPU clock rate when you use some OS on top of hypervisor, but you can control e.g. RAM amount and disk size. I was trying to understand what else can be controlled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guest hardware can be almost anything. But emulating hardware you don't have is *slow*, so in practice choice is limted.

If you want to change the virtual hardware, read the hypervisor's documentation.

Boot a VM and look at the hardware from the guest OS perspective. On a Linux guest start with  `lspci` and `lscpu`. All of these devices are somewhere on the spectrum between emulated, paravirtualized, and passed through unmodified.

For example, QEMU is an emulator that can translate instructions to a different architecture. But on Linux with KVM, if the guest is the same architecture, QEMU is a visualizer that runs code direct on the CPU.  Further, there is some choice in guest hardware. The network card could be an emulated e1000, a paravirtualized virtio, or direct attach  hardware from the host's PCI bus.